# How would one make empathy start when you turn on your computer or log into the computer

Tags: empathy, startup

I am assuming that you need to put it in the startup applications, but i am not completely clear on how to do this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Go to *System → Preferences → Startup Applications* and click the *Add* button.
You'll see something like this:

[image]

The name and comment are just for you to recognise it in the list of startup applications

The command for empathy is just `empathy`

If you're unsure about a command you can start the application, open the *System Monitor* and check the *Command* entry in the process list.
[image]